# Error on config:set : path does not exists

Tags: magento2, shell

I run `bin/magento config:show | grep theme` that returns

> design/theme/theme_id - 5

Then i write `bin/magento config:set design/theme/theme_id 0` that returns

> The "design/theme/theme_id" path does not exist

Why it happens?
Using Magento 2.2.7

Answer (score 0):

The error is thrown in `vendor/magento/module-config/Model/Config/PathValidator.php` on line 44:

```
    if (!array_key_exists($path, $allPaths)) {
        throw new ValidatorException(__('The "%1" path does not exist', $path));
    }
```

I'm not sure about the cause of this bug, but you can comment the exception out, then the `config:set` command will work as expected. Ofcourse the change will be gone after you update the Magento_Config package via composer. 
For a more permanent solution you can patch the Magento_Config module using https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches.